# Restore Ubiquity router with squashfs errors

Tags: linux, squashfs

I have a [Ubiquity EdgeRouter Lite](http://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-lite/) that no longer functions after a powercycle.

Connecting to the serial port, this is the error I get.

```
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 3 seconds
EXT3-fs (sda2): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (sda2): recovery complete
EXT3-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with journal data mode
VFS: Mounted root (unionfs filesystem) on device 0:11.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 284k freed
Algorithmics/MIPS FPU Emulator v1.5
INIT: version 2.88 booting
SQUASHFS error: zlib_inflate error, data probably corrupt
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x1d9fec2
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d9fec2, size 5872
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d9fec2, size 5872
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d9fec2, size 5872
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d9fec2, size 5872
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d9fec2, size 5872
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d9fec2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquiti has a solution on their forums:

- [EdgeMax rescue kit (now you can reinstall EdgeOS from scratch)](http://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/EdgeMax-rescue-kit-now-you-can-reinstall-EdgeOS-from-scratch/m-p/514857)

  > Image URL: http://dl.ubnt.com/firmwares/edgemax/v1.6.0/ER-e100.v1.6.0.4716006.tar